# How to trigger an action in LWC component from aura container

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a an LWC component which is referred from aura wrapper. I need to trigger an action inside the LWC component on a button press from enclosing aura component.
Requesting to provide input on the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `api` methods in LWC. These are exposed to parent components when decorated `api`. Here is an example:

Aura component:

cmp:

```
<lightning:button label="Get From Poc" onclick="{!c.getFromPoc}" />
<c:poc aura:id="poc" />
```

and its JS:

```
getFromPoc : function (component, event, helper) {
    let myData = component.find("poc").getMyData();
    console.log("myData => ", myData);
},
```

Now the child LWC component `poc`:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @api
    getMyData() {
        return 'some data from poc';
    }
}
```

This method `getMyData` is exposed and can be invoked from parent component (Aura or LWC). Syntax will be same as `aura:method` invocation as you can see in aura component `getFromPoc` method.